# Update every 30 Seconds, but only with change in data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update a `div` with id `notication` every 30 seconds, but only if the `notifications.php` script returns a new value.

```
function auto_load(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'notifications.php',
      success: function(data){
         $('#notification').html(data);
      }
    });
}
auto_load(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is ready.
//Refresh auto_load() function after 30 seconds.
setInterval(auto_load,30000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a variable which has the current data, or you can check the `#notification_buble2` element's html and update it if it's different.
For example:

```
var currentData = "";
function auto_load(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'notifications.php',
    success: function(data){
       if(currentData != data) {
           $('#notification').html(data);
           currentData = data;
       }
    }
  });
}
auto_load();
setInterval(auto_load,30000);
```

Comment: Ok great, but can I simply do `var currentData = "<div id="notification_buble2"> </div>";` ? as the data is loaded to this div and there is no other variable I get.

Comment: @PawelGawronski you can, but then you'd have double ids of  `notification_buble2`, which you don't want. Can you give me a sample of what the `notifications.php` script returns?

Comment: @PawelGawronski The way this is you just need to add the variable, an if statement, and a set statement when they're different. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Sure `require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

$tu_nick = $_POST['this_user'];  

$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS upto5 FROM pw WHERE receiver='$tu_nick' AND readed='no'");
$num = mysql_fetch_assoc($counter);
$count = $num['upto5'];


echo'<span class="count">'.$count.'</span>';`

Comment: @PawelGawronski Yeah, so this code should just be take and drop. Leave the existing `notification_buble2` element there, and just change the contents.

Comment: I dont get what you mean

Comment: @PawelGawronski What are you not understanding?

Comment: "and just change the contents", do you mean to do it as I suggested to load this div to var currentData?

Comment: @PawelGawronski The `$('#notification_buble2').html(data);` is changing the contents. So, 1. Set variable(`var currentData = ""`), 2. Check currentData to see if it's changed (`if(currentData != data)`) 3. Change data (`$('#notification_buble2').html(data);`) 4. Update currentData to new value (`currentData = data;`). Does that clear it up?

Comment: it confuses me as you id ask me to leave existing element of div and change content. I do get that I have to compare one to the other etc. but what I dont get is you mentioned about getting doubled id so what or how can I load this content to var element?

Comment: @PawelGawronski Because you asked "can I simply do `var currentData = "<div id="notification_buble2"> `. You just want to set `var currentData = ""`, an empty string, not to the container. The container's content is changed with the AJAX call, so currentData wont have that `notification_buble2` id in it anywhere. You just set it to an empty string initially, and it will update with each request if there is a change.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont get this, I did below but I dont think this is what you mean as not working. i have updated the question with the code after your suggestions.

Comment: @PawelGawronski Did you intentionally put 's around it? I'm not sure what `$actual_notification` is. Is that supposed to be PHP? Right now, if you're in those quotations in the PHP, that is attempting to define a variable that is undefined in javascript when it is rendered.

Comment: I dont get how can I set empty variable in javascript. should that be just `var actual_notification = '';` and than below `var currentData = "actual_notification"` ? I have called empty string "actual_notification"

Comment: @PawelGawronski All you need to set an empty variable is `var currentData = ""`. The "" is an empty string. If it makes you feel better you can do `var currentData = "This is just a random silly string that means nothing and is different than what the first 'data' will return";` but it doesn't help. Just remove all of your $actual_notification stuff. The first call will decide that the values are different and fetch it again.

Comment: OMG @forrestmid I am so sorry for being such a diff.

Your example working great after I have analised code properly and actioned following your comments. I have also added else clause to it so it does load the actual number of notifications upon page refreshed initiated by user when currentData is equal data.

Yet again thank you.

Comment: @PawelGawronski No worries. Welcome to stack overflow! In the future, try to provide only necessary code. In this case we don't need any of the `<script>` tags or anything like that. Just the code I put in my answer is really all you need. I submitted a suggested edit to show you what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve can by done using JavaScript. Down below is sample code of what you're trying to achieve.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
          <head>
             <script type="text/javascript" source="jquery-2.4.1.min.js">
                function showNewList(str) {
                   if (str=="") {
                  document.getElementById("idofselectedmenu").innerHTML="";
                   return;
                  } 
                   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
               } else { // code for IE6, IE5
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("idofselectedmenu").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","handler.php?variable="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
```

With the above in your handler file you'll need to use $_GET['variable'] in order to retrieve the data from the web page.

Comment: I find this method to be simpler and there's loads of information out there available on it.

Comment: This code looks much more complected than what I have posted why would you suggest it how is that better than ajax?

Comment: AJAX is a technique. I suggest you take a look at these resources listed below to fully understand how it works. 

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

https://books.google.tt/books?id=lNxfh4vyWl4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=AJAX&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=AJAX&f=false

Those will help a lot in understanding. Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: to be honest, only ready scripts to than change up to my requirements, never build anything in JS. thank you for resources will definitely have a look